# Matching string with regex containing colon

Tags: java

I try to match different date formats that I parse from different files. One date format is for example: "Thu, 12 Nov 2009 14:17:44 -0000"

When I try to match this string with the first regex I get a true result, when I use the second one I get false.

```
[A-Za-z]{3},\\s+\\d{2}\\s+[A-Za-z]{3}\\s+\\d{2}.*   (1. regex)
[A-Za-z]{3},\\s+\\d{2}\\s+[A-Za-z]{3}\\s+\\d{2}:.*  (2. regex)
```

In my opinion both regex should match the above date format. Where is my failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the last part "\s+\d{2}:.*" was to match the "14:", but you have forgotten the year.  So the parser expects a ":" but finds the 2nd zero in 2009.

What you need is something like this:

```
[A-Za-z]{3},\\s+\\d{2}\\s+[A-Za-z]{3}\\s+\\d{4}\\s+\\d{2}:.*  (2. regex)
```

(I think that should pass :))

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be forgetting the 4 digit year, therefore the second regex isn't corrrect.

The final part of your first regex is matching the first two digits of `2009` and then everything after.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the *year* :

`"[A-Za-z]{3},\\s+\\d{2}\\s+[A-Za-z]{3} \\p{Digit}{4} (\\p{Digit}{2}:){2}[0-9][0-9].*";`

You can also test *hour* in different format.